# Using div class to set css style - not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the CSS and below it is the html code.  Not sure why this setup is not working.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
div.logo img {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 200;  
    position: absolute; 
    display: table-cell; 

}

<div class="a container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="logo"><img  src="logo.png">
```

Comment: Maybe you need add pixels to width (200px). However, what are you trying to do with this? what isn't working?

Comment: html is not recognizing that it's being specified in the css

Comment: This isn't nearly enough for us to give you an answer. Are you including the stylesheet in the head of your document? There is a rogue space between img and src in this. Overall this is just far too vague for us to really help you, include a bit more so we can check it out.

Comment: yes, the style sheet is in the header.

Answer (score 1):

you should set the img "display:block"

Answer (score 1):

Try giving position: relative to the parent container, and give display:block to the div 'logo', maybe it'll work for you then.
Although same piece of code is working for me in CodePen, or attach fiddle along with this for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.logo img {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 200;  
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    border:1px solid red;
}

<div class="a container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="logo">
        <img  src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/42eot71s/